# cannot build using jcabi parent pom

Tags: java, maven-3, aop, aspectj, jcabi

I am trying to use jcabi for logging. As I understand it is easier to inherit my pom from jcabi pom file for setup as described at http://www.jcabi.com/parent/index.html

However I get following error error on "mvn clean install" (has to do with resolving version number)
Any idea on how to resolve this or is it not recommended to inherit from jcabi pom file

```
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.2:
 create    (jcabi-build-number) on project cbm: Execution jcabi-build-number of
goalorg.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.2:create failed: Plugin org.codehaus
.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resol
 ved: 

 Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugi
 n:jar:1.2 -> org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-api:jar:1.8 -> org.codehaus.plexus:p
 lexus-utils:jar:3.0.3: 

Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexu
 s:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.3: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus
  -utils:pom:3.0.3 from/to internal  ....

  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
   rg.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.2:create (jcabi-build-number) on pro
 ject cbm: Execution jcabi-build-number of goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-mav
  en-plugin:1.2:create failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1
2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 

 Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:jar:1.2 
   ->         org.apache.maven.sc
```

Comment: You have a problem with connecting to a repository `Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus  -utils:pom:3.0.3 from/to internal  ....``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer here if relevant to any one

```
        < dependencies>
           <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.12</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
          </dependencies>
       <build>
       <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
               <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ajc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```